# Pass variable from php while loop to javascript function

Tags: php, javascript

I have some images and what i want to do is on mouse over each pic to change a text inside a div  which is the image title.

So here's my code:

```
<?php
...

$i=0;
while($i<$imageno)
{

echo'
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText() {document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "'.$title[$i].'";}
</script>';

if ($imagine[$i]){
echo '<div onmouseover="changeText()"><img src="'.$imagine[$i].'"></div>';
};
$i++;
}

...
?>
```

But my script shows only the tscription of my last picture...

Please help!
...without Ajax

Comment: Asided from the function definition issue outlined in the answers below, you are using `getElementById()` in every iteration which means the same element will be affected every time. You cannot have more than one element with the same ID, they must be unique. You will need to show more code (namely the part where you define the element with `id="title"` before we can tell you the correct solution.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass variable to `changeText` function:

```
echo '<div onmouseover="changeText('".$title[$i]."')"><img src="'.$imagine[$i].'"></div>';
```

And to change `changeText` function like this:

```
function changeText( myText ) {document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = myText;}
```

Comment: `echo '<div onmouseover="changeText(\''.str_replace("'", "\\'", htmlspecialchars($title[$i])).'\')"><img src="'.$imagine[$i].'"></div>';`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put the function definition in the loop, and you need to use parameter.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText(title) {document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = title;}
</script>

<?php
//... 
$i=0;
while($i<$imageno) {
  if ($imagine[$i]){
    $title = json_encode(htmlspecialchars($title[$i]));
    echo '<div onmouseover="changeText('.$title.')"><img src="'.$imagine[$i].'"></div>';
  };
  $i++;
}
//...
?>
```

Comment: Check your quotes (there are not enough of them)

Comment: I have just realised this still wont work because of the static `getElementById()` - it will affect the same element on every iteration so you still won't see an effect for anything other than the last `$title[$i]`. The OP needs to provide more code. Also you should escape literal `'` characters in `$title[$i]` as well as the `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: @DaveRandom Yep, assume he has only one title div. And you should use `htmlspecialchars` to escape `'`, use `str_replace` to `"\\'"` won't help because `'` need to be `&#039;`.

Comment: Yeh I guess that would work, although I think `\'` *should* work as well, since you are escaping it in a JS string literal it should have identical syntax to the way you do it in a raw JS file. And even if he has more than one `title` element only the first one would be affected because you can't have duplicated IDs

Comment: [JSFiddle says](http://jsfiddle.net/kuVZA/2/) that you have to use `\'`. When you use `&#039;` you get a syntax error, you actually have to escape the entity too - `\&#039;` (in Chrome, at least)

Comment: @DaveRandom OMG, Haven't noticed that. Now I turn to use `json_encode` for javascript variable, then it should be ok.

Comment: @DaveRandom And that's why I don't like to use php and javascript like this.

Comment: SOLVED. <div onmouseover="changeText(\''.$title[$i].'\')"> and function outside the loop: function changeText(myText){
document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = myText;
}